# Which java class is preferred to read a web page into a string under Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient, html

I’ve seen a number of solutions to this but not sure which is the preferred methodology or class to use including import and libs?  I prefer to use native Android libs and am using API 23 but that can be changed.

Comment: Have tried jsoup ?

Comment: Nope.  Never heard of it.  Is it a native Android framework?  I’m trying to avoid the use of 3rd party libs.

Comment: it is a java library to parse html and css , you can add it  to your project through gradle .  if you are  just  trying to convert html to  plain string  you try the HTML class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't even necessarily an Android question. If your goal is only to get a `String` representation of a webpage (no parsing), you should be able to use classes that are also present in Java SE like `URL` and `InputStream` without any problem.

For example (no exception handling done here, do it yourself as needed). You can use a try-with-resources or just close the connection / input stream when done in a finally block.

```
// create the url object and open the connection
URL url = new URL("http://somewhere.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// read the webpage  a line at a time and append it to a `StringBuilder`
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
// here is the html
String html = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Of course you have to be careful and double-check that a given class from Java SE is also available from the Android SDK.

Comment: Good point, subtle difference. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: That’s exactly what I do for my web apps using Java SE.  I have routines built already but wasn’t sure they would be applicable under Android.  I like the paradigm of compatibility with my other apps.  The import Java.net.* was giving me grief so I think I need to add a lib.

Comment: @zappullae Check out the documentation on http://d.android.com. Usually it is fasted to google "Android <class name>" for the documentation for a specific class in the Android APIs. For example, "Android HttpURLConnection" gives this: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection. Note that it should be `import java.net.*`, not `import Java.net.*`. Can you see the difference?

Comment: yes I know the difference in the import. SO upper cased it on me in my response and I mistook an unused import for an error . Thanks for the heads up on the doc format. That will help in the future.